# CakePHP Redirect to external absolute URL

Tags: php, url, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP, $this->redirect works fine for redirecting to an internal page with internal urls.  Is there any way to redirect a user to an external page?

For example:
    $this->redirectTo('http://google.com');

Comment: `header("Location: http://google.com")` is one option, assuming no output was sent beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->redirect()` works fine with external URL's as well.

```
$this->redirect('http://www.example.com');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#flow-control

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason.  Here is an example:
`$this->redirect('http://google.com');` redirects me to `http://www.mysite.comhttp//google.com`

Comment: Tested; Works fine for me with latest version of CakePHP. It seems to be treating it as a relative URL; double check for any typos.

Comment: There are no typos.  I really don't know what the problem is.  It seems to be taking any string you put and removed the colon, then treating it as a relative url.

Comment: `redirect()` is essentially calling `header("Location: " . Router::url('http://google.com', true)); exit;`. `Router::url()` should simply return the untouched URL if `((strpos($url, '://') !== false`. Can you test what `Router::url('http://google.com', true));` returns? Checking `strpos($url, '://')` might also be good. If both of those look alright, I don't know what else it could be besides a wonky CakePHP install or something, somewhere messing with the `beforeRedirect` method.

Comment: Ah yes, I got it now.  I realized there is a beforeRedirect method used to deal with the load balancer and secure requests.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction!  `$this->redirect()` works

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`$this->redirect('http://www.google.com', null, true);`

Comment: This doesn't work.  The 2nd parameter should be a status code.

Comment: `null` and `true` are the default second and third parameters respectively. This is the same as: `$this->redirect('http://www.google.com');`